# Media Player Prepared Failed On API Level 23+

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make a Audio Player , which perform these tasks:

1.Record Audio.
 2.Play Recorded Audio File(WAV,PCM)

I am able to do these both on API level 23 and below it . But when I am trying to target higher API level , I am getting an exception in preparing MediaPlayer    `W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1`  .  I have been reading all the question and answer related to it in Stack Overflow but nothing solves my problem.  Below are the implementation of my code.Please help resolve this.
While checking existence of file by file.exists() returns true, but setDataSource internal method saying file dosen't exist.

```
package cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.DbmHandler;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.GLAudioVisualizationView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.model.AudioChannel;
import cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.model.AudioSampleRate;
import cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.model.AudioSource;
import omrecorder.AudioChunk;
import omrecorder.OmRecorder;
import omrecorder.PullTransport;
import omrecorder.Recorder;

public class AudioRecorderActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements PullTransport.OnAudioChunkPulledListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private String filePath;
    private AudioSource source;
    private AudioChannel channel;
    private AudioSampleRate sampleRate;
    private int color;
    private boolean autoStart;
    private boolean keepDisplayOn;

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Recorder recorder;
    private VisualizerHandler visualizerHandler;

    private Timer timer;
    private MenuItem saveMenuItem;
    private int recorderSecondsElapsed;
    private int playerSecondsElapsed;
    private boolean isRecording;

    private RelativeLayout contentLayout;
    private GLAudioVisualizationView visualizerView;
    private TextView statusView;
    private TextView timerView;
    private ImageButton restartView;
    private ImageButton recordView;
    private ImageButton playView;
    private File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aar_activity_audio_recorder);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            filePath = savedInstanceState.getString(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_FILE_PATH);
            source = (AudioSource) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_SOURCE);
            channel = (AudioChannel) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_CHANNEL);
            sampleRate = (AudioSampleRate) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_SAMPLE_RATE);
            color = savedInstanceState.getInt(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_COLOR);
            autoStart = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_AUTO_START);
            keepDisplayOn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_KEEP_DISPLAY_ON);
        } else {
            filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_FILE_PATH);
            source = (AudioSource) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_SOURCE);
            channel = (AudioChannel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_CHANNEL);
            sampleRate = (AudioSampleRate) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_SAMPLE_RATE);
            color = getIntent().getIntExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_COLOR, Color.BLACK);
            autoStart = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_AUTO_START, false);
            keepDisplayOn = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_KEEP_DISPLAY_ON, false);
        }

        if (keepDisplayOn) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Util.getDarkerColor(color)));
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.aar_ic_clear));
        }

        visualizerView = new GLAudioVisualizationView.Builder(this)
                .setLayersCount(1)
                .setWavesCount(6)
                .setWavesHeight(R.dimen.aar_wave_height)
                .setWavesFooterHeight(R.dimen.aar_footer_height)
                .setBubblesPerLayer(20)
                .setBubblesSize(R.dimen.aar_bubble_size)
                .setBubblesRandomizeSize(true)
                .setBackgroundColor(Util.getDarkerColor(color))
                .setLayerColors(new int[]{color})
                .build();

        contentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        timerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        restartView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.restart);
        recordView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.record);
        playView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);

        contentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Util.getDarkerColor(color));
        contentLayout.addView(visualizerView, 0);
        restartView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (Util.isBrightColor(color)) {
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.aar_ic_clear)
                    .setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.aar_ic_check)
                    .setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            statusView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            timerView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            restartView.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
            recordView.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
            playView.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (autoStart && !isRecording) {
            toggleRecording(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            visualizerView.onResume();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        restartRecording(null);
        try {
            visualizerView.onPause();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        restartRecording(null);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        try {
            visualizerView.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_FILE_PATH, filePath);
        outState.putInt(AndroidAudioRecorder.EXTRA_COLOR, color);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.aar_audio_recorder, menu);
        saveMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save);
        saveMenuItem.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.aar_ic_check));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int i = item.getItemId();
        if (i == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        } else if (i == R.id.action_save) {
            selectAudio();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioChunkPulled(AudioChunk audioChunk) {
        float amplitude = isRecording ? (float) audioChunk.maxAmplitude() : 0f;
        visualizerHandler.onDataReceived(amplitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        stopPlaying();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    private void selectAudio() {
        stopRecording();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    public void toggleRecording(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        Util.wait(100, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isRecording) {
                    pauseRecording();
                } else {
                    resumeRecording();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void togglePlaying(View v) {
        pauseRecording();
        Util.wait(100, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isPlaying()) {
                    stopPlaying();
                } else {
                    if (isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable())
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AudioRecorderActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Log.v("Permission", "Readingpermission is granted");
                        }
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AudioRecorderActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.v("Permission", "Writingpermission is granted");
                    }
                    startPlaying();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }

    public void restartRecording(View v) {
        if (isRecording) {
            stopRecording();
        } else if (isPlaying()) {
            stopPlaying();
        } else {
            visualizerHandler = new VisualizerHandler();
            visualizerView.linkTo(visualizerHandler);
            visualizerView.release();
            if (visualizerHandler != null) {
                visualizerHandler.stop();
            }
        }
        saveMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        statusView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        restartView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        recordView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_rec);
        timerView.setText("00:00:00");
        recorderSecondsElapsed = 0;
        playerSecondsElapsed = 0;
    }

    private void resumeRecording() {
        isRecording = true;
        saveMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        statusView.setText(R.string.aar_recording);
        statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        restartView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        recordView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_pause);
        playView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_play);

        visualizerHandler = new VisualizerHandler();
        visualizerView.linkTo(visualizerHandler);

        if (recorder == null) {
            timerView.setText("00:00:00");


            recorder = OmRecorder.wav(
                    new PullTransport.Default(Util.getMic(source, channel, sampleRate), AudioRecorderActivity.this),
                    new File(filePath));
        }
        recorder.resumeRecording();

        startTimer();
    }

    private void pauseRecording() {
        isRecording = false;
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            saveMenuItem.setVisible(true);
        }
        statusView.setText(R.string.aar_paused);
        statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        restartView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recordView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_rec);
        playView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_play);

        visualizerView.release();
        if (visualizerHandler != null) {
            visualizerHandler.stop();
        }

        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.pauseRecording();
        }

        stopTimer();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        visualizerView.release();
        if (visualizerHandler != null) {
            visualizerHandler.stop();
        }

        recorderSecondsElapsed = 0;
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.stopRecording();
            recorder = null;
        }

        stopTimer();
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        try {
            stopRecording();
            cleanUp();
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(filePath);
            player.prepare();
            player.setVolume(100f, 100f);
            player.setLooping(false);
            player.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        visualizerView.linkTo(DbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(this, player));
        visualizerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.setOnCompletionListener(AudioRecorderActivity.this);
            }
        });

        timerView.setText("00:00:00");
        statusView.setText(R.string.aar_playing);
        statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_stop);

        playerSecondsElapsed = 0;
        startTimer();
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        statusView.setText("");
        statusView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aar_ic_play);

        visualizerView.release();
        if (visualizerHandler != null) {
            visualizerHandler.stop();
        }

        if (player != null) {
            try {
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        stopTimer();
    }

    private boolean isPlaying() {
        try {
            return player != null && player.isPlaying() && !isRecording;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        stopTimer();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTimer();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    private void cleanUp() {
        if (player != null) {
            visualizerView.release();
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.pause();
            }
            player.release();
            player = null;

        }
    }

    private void updateTimer() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isRecording) {
                    recorderSecondsElapsed++;
                    timerView.setText(Util.formatSeconds(recorderSecondsElapsed));
                } else if (isPlaying()) {
                    playerSecondsElapsed++;
                    timerView.setText(Util.formatSeconds(playerSecondsElapsed));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: IOExceptions tells us that there is an error while reading the file. or file may  be currupt. Did you try using another file path? or file from internet.

Comment: setDataSource throwing file not exist false where in file exist.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh please help

Comment: I didn't understand your previous comment. You are saying setdatasource is throwing "file not exist" error? Can you paste the log from the logcat of that exception?